# What is this variable suposed to do on a lua generic for

Tags: lua

I am new with lua. There is something I just can't understand about the so called generic for:

```
local L0 = {69, 145, 3, 70, 73, 30, 35}   
local L1, L2, L3 = nil, nil, nil

for L1, L2 in L0, L3 do  
print("Something") 

end
```

What is the purpose of L3 next to the table?

Comment: That doesn't look right. There's no `ipairs` or `pairs` involved?

Comment: Where did you get that code from? It is not valid to do a for-loop over a table [directly, without calling `pairs` or `ipairs` or another iterator] in any version of Lua I am familiar with.

Comment: This was a code I got from decompiling a script without debug info. There were no functions involved. It came out this way so I got confused.

Comment: `for L1, L2 in next,L0 do ... end` works.

Comment: What is `next` suposed to do there?

Comment: Learning Lua from decompiled scripts is not a very good idea. learn the basics first, then go back to the script you're interested in.  regarding next read the Lua manual, [next](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-next)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5):

A generic for loop has the following syntax:

> ```
> stat ::= for namelist in explist do block end
>   namelist ::= Name {‘,’ Name}
> ```
>
> The loop starts by evaluating explist to produce four values: an
> iterator function, a state, an initial value for the control variable,
> and a closing value.

So in your case

```
for L1, L2 in L0, L3 do  
  print("Something") 
end
```

`L0` is supposed to be the iterator function and Lua tries to call it. As `L0` is a table value, you face an error for trying to call a table value.
And even if `L0` were an iterator function you're still 2 values short. Actually as L3 is nil you're 3 values short. You see this code doesn't make much sense.

Most times generic for loops are used with `ipairs` or `pairs` which looks like

```
for k,v in pairs(sometable) do
 --block
end
```

or

```
for i,v in ipairs(someTable) do
-- block
end
```

I don't know where you found that code but I'd suggest you look for another resource for learning Lua.

http://www.lua.org is a good starting point. Both the manual and the free ebook verison of Programming in Lua are excellent resources.

Comment: I get it now. `L3` is useless for this application, and to go through all the values on the table I just use `pairs(L0)`. Thanks